# Query to return record value in column instead of row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need assistance in creating a query. I have Client table that has unique client info - identified by their unique ClientID.  I also have a Client_UserDefinedFields table that contains values of custom data for clients.  They are linked via the ClientID and there may be many records for a ClientID in this Client_UserDefinedFields table.

My situation is that there are 3 custom data fields that I need to know the values for a given client (as shown by my CASE statement).  My current query is bringing back the client 3 times (a row for each value) and I want to only see the client once (one row) and have these values shown as columns.  Not sure if this is possible or how to that.  Furthermore, when I tried using a CASE statement in my select, I cannot use AS 'fieldname' to identify it -  since it's giving me an error on the AS keyword.

An example of my current SQL SELECT statement

```
    SELECT
        c.ClientID
      , c.LastName
      , c.FirstName
      , c.MiddleName
      , CASE WHEN cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink = '93fb3820-38aa-4655-8aad-a8dce8aede' THEN cudf.UDF_ReportValue --AS 'DA Status'
             WHEN cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink = '2144a742-08c5-4c96-b9e4-d6f1f56c76' THEN cudf.UDF_ReportValue --AS 'FHAP Status'
             WHEN cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink = 'c3d29be9-af58-4241-a02d-9ae9b43ffa' THEN cudf.UDF_ReportValue --AS 'HCRA Status'
        END
    FROM Client_Program cp
    INNER JOIN client c ON c.ulink = cp.clientulink
    INNER JOIN code_program p ON p.ulink = cp.programulink
    INNER JOIN Code_System_State css ON c.ContactMailingStateUlink = css.ulink 
    INNER JOIN Code_ClientStatus ccs ON c.ClientStatusULink = ccs.ULink
    INNER JOIN Client_UserDefinedField cudf ON c.ULink = cudf.ClientULink
    AND cp.ProgramStatusULink = '1' -- Open (active) program
    AND c.ClientStatusULink = '10000000' --Active client
    AND cp.programulink in ('7280f4a7-cd94-49be-86ad-a74421ff6f',
      '0a9b94a3-edd7-4918-b79c-bf2b20f9da',
      '54f6c691-2eba-49e5-8380-85f5349bca',
      'ed8c497d-d4fe-41d7-a218-4235fd0734',
      '5be826f0-b3c3-4ebe-871d-4d20b56da5')
     AND cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink IN ('93fb3820-38aa-4655-8aad-a8dce8aede', -- DA Status
                                              '2144a742-08c5-4c96-b9e4-d6f1f56c76', --FHAP Status
'c3d29be9-af58-4241-a02d-9ae9b43ffa') --HCRA Status
```

Again, my issue is that I don't want to bring back the same client multiple times if they had more than one entry in the Client_UserDefinedFields table. I'd like to bring this in one row with each "Status" field correctly populated as a columns.  How do I do this?  Here's a sample of my current output:

```
ClientID        LastName    FirstName   MiddleName  PCHP/HCH Status DA Status   FHAP Status         HCRA Status         
XXXXXXXXXXXX    River       Mike        Allan       Active          (null)      - None Selected -   (null)              
XXXXXXXXXXXX    River       Mike        Allan       Active          Active      (null)              (null)              
XXXXXXXXXXXX    River       Mike        Allan       Active          (null)      (null)              - None Selected -
```

Ultimately would like to see just the one record with all the values

```
ClientID        LastName    FirstName   MiddleName  PCHP/HCH Status DA Status   FHAP Status         HCRA Status         
XXXXXXXXXXXX    River       Mike        Allan       Active          Active      - None Selected -   - None Selected -
```

Examples are very helpful as I'm not a SQL guru.  Thank you!

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Why do you need the case statement.   You have limit the those values in the join.

Comment: If you can include some sample data and the expected output from that data in tabular format, it'll be a lot easier understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: @paparazzo - The Client_UserDefinedField table has many user defined fields for a client.  If I don't include the "AND cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink IN" in the WHERE clause, I get back 100's of records for the same client.  I'm only interested in those 3 status fields along with the client's main record data in the client table.

Comment: @Tab Alleman - I saw this post prior to posting mine, but I don't want to pivot the entire record, just combine (if possible) these output rows for a client into one.  I've added a "final result" of what I'd like to accomplish to the end of my original post.  Thank you again.

Comment: Right not you have cut it off to where  the sample output is not valid.

Comment: @DataCrypt I don't understand what you mean by "not wanting to pivot the entire record"?   Using the solution in the duplicate, you can group by the first 4 columns and pivot the last one.

Comment: @Tab Alleman - I'm not familiar with the PIVOT or "grouping" certain columns and pivoting the rest.  Anyway you can please provide an example specific to my query/data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.ClientID,
   c.LastName,
   c.FirstName,
   c.MiddleName,
   CASE
       WHEN cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink = '93fb3820-38aa-4655-8aad-a8dce8aede' THEN
           cudf.UDF_ReportValue AS 'DA Status'
       WHEN cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink = '2144a742-08c5-4c96-b9e4-d6f1f56c76' THEN
           cudf.UDF_ReportValue AS 'FHAP Status'
       WHEN cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink = 'c3d29be9-af58-4241-a02d-9ae9b43ffa' THEN
           cudf.UDF_ReportValue AS 'HCRA Status'
   END
INTO #Temp
FROM Client_Program cp
INNER JOIN client c
    ON c.ulink = cp.clientulink
INNER JOIN code_program p
    ON p.ulink = cp.programulink
INNER JOIN Code_System_State css
    ON c.ContactMailingStateUlink = css.ulink
INNER JOIN Code_ClientStatus ccs
    ON c.ClientStatusULink = ccs.ULink
INNER JOIN Client_UserDefinedField cudf
    ON c.ULink = cudf.ClientULink
       AND cp.ProgramStatusULink = '1' -- Open (active) program
       AND c.ClientStatusULink = '10000000' --Active client
       AND cp.programulink IN ( '7280f4a7-cd94-49be-86ad-a74421ff6f', '0a9b94a3-edd7-4918-b79c-bf2b20f9da',
                                '54f6c691-2eba-49e5-8380-85f5349bca', 'ed8c497d-d4fe-41d7-a218-4235fd0734',
                                '5be826f0-b3c3-4ebe-871d-4d20b56da5'
                              )
       AND cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink IN (   '93fb3820-38aa-4655-8aad-a8dce8aede', -- DA Status
                                                   '2144a742-08c5-4c96-b9e4-d6f1f56c76'
                                               ); --FHAP Status

SELECT COALESCE(A.CilentID, B.ClientID, C.ClientID),LastName,
   FirstName, MiddleName, [DA Status], [FHAP Status], [HCRA Status] FROM 
(SELECT ClientID, LastName, FirstName, [DA Status] FROM #Temp WHERE [DA Status] IS NOT NULL) AS A FULL OUTER JOIN  
(SELECT ClientID, LastName, FirstName, [FHAP Status] FROM #Temp WHERE [FHAP Status] IS NOT NULL) AS B ON A.ClientID = B.ClientID FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT ClientID, LastName, FirstName, [HCRA Status] FROM #Temp WHERE [HCRA Status] IS NOT NULL) AS C ON C.ClientID = A.ClientID
```

Comment: Your COALESCE statement works!!  However, it's outputing Column1, DA Status, FHAP Status, HCRA Status and I'm not getting the LastName, FIrstName columns.  How do I correct this?  I have other columns I'd like to add too. So I think we're onto something here!  I can turn this into a stored proc to run my report from afterwards if required.

Comment: @DataCrypt Edited. yes you can create stored proc. Do not forget to mark as solution if it is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Can I add the SELECT and SELECT COALESCE into one VIEW (i.e. can a view have the two select statements)?  Was hoping I could, but not sure.  Otherwise, I'll have to create a SP for it.  Thank you!

Comment: Common table expression (CTE) can solve your problem. CTEs are temporary result sets that are defined within the execution scope of a single statement and they can be used in views. However, I would Recommend you to create SP.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.  I'll go ahead with the SP.

Comment: Well, today I was told the user needs this in real-time and our old reporting tool will NOT run queries directly nor call/run a SP.  It can only get data from views and tables directly.  So, how can I run both the original select and select COALESCE in one view/call to bring back the COALESCE data?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code - but the PIVOT command would work:

```
SELECT
c.ClientID
, c.LastName
, c.FirstName
, c.MiddleName
, CASE WHEN cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink = '93fb3820-38aa-4655-8aad-a8dce8aede' THEN cudf.UDF_ReportValue --AS 'DA Status'
     WHEN cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink = '2144a742-08c5-4c96-b9e4-d6f1f56c76' THEN cudf.UDF_ReportValue --AS 'FHAP Status'
     WHEN cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink = 'c3d29be9-af58-4241-a02d-9ae9b43ffa' THEN cudf.UDF_ReportValue --AS 'HCRA Status'
   END
 FROM Client_Program cp
INNER JOIN code_program p ON p.ulink = cp.programulink
INNER JOIN Code_System_State css ON c.ContactMailingStateUlink = css.ulink 
INNER JOIN Code_ClientStatus ccs ON c.ClientStatusULink = ccs.ULink
INNER JOIN client c ON c.ulink = cp.clientulink
INNER JOIN (
    select * 
    from ( select ClientULink, UserDefinedFieldFormatULink , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientULink ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
            from Client_UserDefinedField
            where UserDefinedFieldFormatULink IN ('93fb3820-38aa-4655-8aad-a8dce8aede', -- DA Status
                 '2144a742-08c5-4c96-b9e4-d6f1f56c76')--FHAP Status
        ) as c
        PIVOT (
            MAX(UserDefinedFieldFormatULink) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3])
        ) as pvt
    ) cudf ON c.ULink = cudf.ClientULink
AND cp.ProgramStatusULink = '1' -- Open (active) program
AND c.ClientStatusULink = '10000000' --Active client
AND cp.programulink in ('7280f4a7-cd94-49be-86ad-a74421ff6f',
   '0a9b94a3-edd7-4918-b79c-bf2b20f9da',
  '54f6c691-2eba-49e5-8380-85f5349bca',
  'ed8c497d-d4fe-41d7-a218-4235fd0734',
  '5be826f0-b3c3-4ebe-871d-4d20b56da5')
```

Comment: Thank you, but untested and when I add your change I get the following error "1 The correlation name 'cudf' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause."  Not sure how to solve it.

Comment: I only see it once - it's hard because I can't test.  I am guessing that if you added it to your existing statement then it is probably in there twice (you original reference, then mine added).  I would just replace your query with this entirely.

Comment: I tried it exactly as pasted and get an error "Invalid Column name "UserDefinedFieldFormatUlink" at the very first CASE WHEN cudf.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly then from my side below is the solution

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    c.ClientID
  , c.LastName
  , c.FirstName
  , c.MiddleName
  , (CASE WHEN cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink = '93fb3820-38aa-4655-8aad-a8dce8aede' THEN cudf.UDF_ReportValue ELSE NULL END)  AS 'DA Status'
    ,(CASE WHEN cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink = '2144a742-08c5-4c96-b9e4-d6f1f56c76' THEN cudf.UDF_ReportValue ELSE NULL END)  AS 'FHAP Status'
    ,(CASE WHEN cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink = 'c3d29be9-af58-4241-a02d-9ae9b43ffa' THEN cudf.UDF_ReportValue ELSE NULL END) AS 'HCRA Status'

FROM Client_Program cp
INNER JOIN client c ON c.ulink = cp.clientulink
INNER JOIN code_program p ON p.ulink = cp.programulink
INNER JOIN Code_System_State css ON c.ContactMailingStateUlink = css.ulink 
INNER JOIN Code_ClientStatus ccs ON c.ClientStatusULink = ccs.ULink
INNER JOIN Client_UserDefinedField cudf ON c.ULink = cudf.ClientULink
AND cp.ProgramStatusULink = '1' -- Open (active) program
AND c.ClientStatusULink = '10000000' --Active client
AND cp.programulink in ('7280f4a7-cd94-49be-86ad-a74421ff6f',
  '0a9b94a3-edd7-4918-b79c-bf2b20f9da',
  '54f6c691-2eba-49e5-8380-85f5349bca',
  'ed8c497d-d4fe-41d7-a218-4235fd0734',
  '5be826f0-b3c3-4ebe-871d-4d20b56da5')
 AND cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink IN ('93fb3820-38aa-4655-8aad-a8dce8aede', -- DA Status
                                          '2144a742-08c5-4c96-b9e4-d6f1f56c76')--FHAP Status
```

Comment: this results still brings back 3 rows without combing the status values into the one client output row.