# Run two select statements in one view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some SQL that is broken into two SELECT statements.  The first SELECT statement inserts results INTO a temp table.  The second SELECT statement is a COALESCE that reads data from the temp table the first one inserted data into.  I need to be able to run these together (one after the other) and unfortunately cannot put these into a Stored Procedure due to the old reporting tool my company uses.  The reporting tool must read from a VIEW or a TABLE.  I wanted to put these into a VIEW, but have researched that a view cannot have more than one SELECT.  Any ideas and examples on how to accomplish this?  My original post/solution showing the SQL is in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161290/query-to-return-record-value-in-column-instead-of-row).

Comment: You can break those queries into CTE's (not using temp tables) and do it in one view.

Comment: Might be worth editing in here that your second select uses the temp table *multiple times*. (Which definitely should steer things towards a CTE and away from subqueries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temp table select could be converted to be a CTE (With clause), and the 2nd part the select query of the view.

Alternatively you could just inline it with sub-selects, but depending on complexity that might make it harder to maintain.

```
CREATE VIEW yourView AS
WITH myFirstSelect(someFields) AS
(
    SELECT somefields FROM sometable
)
SELECT * from myFirstSelect
```

Docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: How do I format the WITH when my first SELECT looks like this:
SELECT c.ClientID,
   c.LastName,
   c.FirstName,
   c.MiddleName,
   ccs.Description AS 'PCHP/HCH Status', --formerly Client Status
   CASE WHEN cudf.UserDefinedFieldFormatULink = '93fb3820-38aa-4655-8aad-a8dce8aede65' THEN cudf.UDF_ReportValue END AS 'DA Status',
   p.Description AS ProgramDescription,
   cp.StartDate,
   cp.EndDate
INTO #TempTest

Comment: remove the INTO #TestTest at the end, and put the select inside the WITH clause. There is no From clause in that statement, so I assume its a fragment

Comment: Got it!  Worked!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Andrew - I just noticed an issue.  With  my original two SELECT statements (using the COALESCE), I get back one record per client with all the Status fields (i.e. the reason I use the COALESCE), rather than them showing up as many records - one for each of the status.  Anyhow, using the CTE, I'm getting duplicate records!  It's acting different than the original query.  Thoughts?  Using a SELECT DISTINCT on the COALESCE appears to fix it, but the result count is still different.

Comment: There must be a difference in how you have transposed the query, nothing about moving an insert into temp to a CTE would change duplicate handling itself.